# How to convert an array of stream in Contents to PRIndirectRefernce?

Tags: itext, pdftotext

I am trying to read pdf and get the text present in it. Using Nugget iTextSharp -LGPL v4.1.5  . (I am not allowed to use ITextsharp v5.5.13 and it makes life difficult)

```
private string GetTextFromPage(PdfReader pdfReader, int page)
{
     StringBuilder pageText = new StringBuilder();
     var cpage = pdfReader.GetPageN(page);
     var content = cpage.Get(PdfName.CONTENTS);

     //Error for casting Pdfarray to PRIndirectReference
     var indirectReference = (PRIndirectReference)content;
}
```

Getting Exception

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfArray' to type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRIndirectReference'.

Kindly suggest how to handle PdfArray object (multiple streams in contents)

Comment: how about iterating over the indirect references in the array?

Comment: I tried using foreach but then foreach function cannot operate  with variable of type PDFObject because PDFObject does not contain defination of GetEnumerator.

Comment: Here content in ' var indirectReference = (PRIndirectReference)content; '  contains multiple streams thats why it gives exception while type casting to PRIndirectReference . Only if it was single stream it would work fine.

Comment: *"I tried using foreach but then foreach function cannot operate with variable of type PDFObject because PDFObject does not contain defination of GetEnumerator"* - obviously `PdfObject` doesn't define `GetEnumerator`, why should it. But you can obviously *test* the type of content, and if it *is* a `PdfArray`, you can *cast* it to `PdfArray`, and `PdfArray` (at least in iText 5.5.x) *does* define `GetEnumerator`. And even if that doesn't work, there still is the good old `for` loop using an integer index up to `Size` of the array in which you can retrieve using `GetAsStream(int idx)`...

Comment: *"Here content in ' var indirectReference = (PRIndirectReference)content; ' contains multiple streams thats why it gives exception while type casting to PRIndirectReference . Only if it was single stream it would work fine."* - you know how check whether an object is of a given type, don't you? That should be part of C# 101...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I did following changes and it solved the problem. 
            
            var content = cpage.Get(PdfName.CONTENTS);

            var pdfArray = content as PdfArray;

            if (pdfArray != null)
            {
                for (int index = 0; index < pdfArray.Size; index++)
                {
                    var pdfItem = pdfArray[index];
                    var indirectReference = (PRIndirectReference)pdfItem; }

Answer (score 0):

I am not too versed in c# but the java code should be easily transferable to c#
I would do it like this:

```
private byte[] getTextFromPage(PdfReader pdfReader, int page){
     PdfDictionary cpage = pdfReader.GetPageN(page);
     PdfObject content = cpage.get(PdfName.CONTENTS);

     return getContent(content);
}    

private byte[] getContent(PdfObject content) throws IOException {
          byte[] result=null;
          switch (content.type()){
            case PdfObject.INDIRECT:
              PRIndirectReference ref = (PRIndirectReference) content;
              PdfObject directObject = PdfReader.getPdfObject(ref);
              result = getContent(directObject);
              break;
            case PdfObject.ARRAY:
              ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              PdfArray cArray = (PdfArray) content;
              for(Object object : cArray.getArrayList()) {
               baos.write(getContent((PdfObject) object));
              }
              result = baos.toByteArray();
              break;
            case PdfObject.STREAM:
              PRStream stream = (PRStream) PdfReader.getPdfObject(content);
              result = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
              break;

            default:
              throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported content type");
          }
          return result;
        }
```

But this is only a small step in retrieving the text. You need the whole operator processing, leading, spacing, scaling, font handling etc. So to completely write it from scratch is a big task...

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution!